# Boolean acting strange

Tags: modifiers

[image][image: Screen shots of 3 steps]

I cannot find anything regarding the problem im having with blender..I only been using it for 3 weeks.
I open up blender and then shift-A to add another cube. I then go into edit mode and press bar to search for boolean. When I click on boolen to apply to my new cube, (or any new object) it disappears.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve/expecting to happen by doing this?

Comment: What are you trying to do using booleans on meshes that do not intersect?

Comment: It seems like you misunderstood, what [boolean operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons) are. The Manual also provides useful examples on the [boolean modifier page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html#boolean-modifier).

Comment: Thanks for replies, I added another picture of what I use actually trying to do..Practicing using boolean to cut out part of an object. Wasnt trying to join or anything like that

Comment: You're messing up Edit mode Boolean and Object mode Boolean. Edit mode has its own Boolean (not modifier) as of new Blender versions, maybe 2.77. As you're in Edit mode for the object which is nothing other than cube there isn't anything to intersect and quite obviously it disappears after intersecting with null.

Answer (score 1):

First of all:
I assume, the feature you are looking for is Join (Ctrl+J). Therefore you have to be in objectmode.

But as mentioned in the comments of your post, 
booleans only give results with intersecting Objects.

Also, the "Intersect(Boolean)" tool only works if both meshes you want to perform the boolean with are in the same Object. This tool performs a boolean operation with the Selected and unselected parts of your object.

[image: Boolean]

To perform a bool between two seperate objects you have to use the boolean modifier or addons like booltool (which are basically also using the boolean modifier)

Comment: Thanks for replies, I added another picture of what I use actually trying to do..Practicing using boolean to cut out part of an object. Wasnt trying to join or anything like that.. Guess i got to just keep at it :)

Comment: You are using the wrong tool. the Intersect(Boolean) works only in edit mode. I also explained this in my answer ;-)

Comment: To use boolean operations on different objects use the boolean modifier.